# JQuery Validate Regex Password Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, jquery-validate

I have been reading about how to manipulate regex, and I do think I have the correct formula for my purpose, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

This is my code

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
    if (!regex.test(value)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I added this method to my password in the `.validate({rules{}});`
It is linked properly, but whatever I input in the text box I get the message I wrote in the `.validate({messages{}});`
the user should be only allowed to input letters and numbers, and seeing other methods posted on this site I tried to mimic and copy them, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
   return /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test(value)
});
```